# JavaScript objects explanation

Tags: javascript

Why are these two variables different? I've been reading [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) and I still don't fully grasp it.

**Variable 1:**

```
<textarea id="code">
  //...[buncha code here]
</textarea>
var example = document.querySelector('#code');
```

**Variable 2:**

var example = "[buncha code here]";

Substitute inside the brackets with whatever code you desire. When referencing the first variable, you must use **`example.value`** instead of just **`example`** or it returns **`[object HTMLTextAreaElement]`**. Is that because it's not a string?

How do I manually set a variable (like in the Variable 2 example) to contain code that can be evaluated, e.g. with **`eval(example.value)`**?

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to do, `eval()` is not the way.

Comment: Using eval() was just an example. I'm not using it. I just want to know how to properly set a variable to match what is pulled via document.querySelector('#code');

Comment: @daveycroqet: Try not to use w3schools to much as they are well known for not keeping up to date and not adhering to the W3C standards in the past to much. Also their certifications mean very little due to that. See [**w3fools**](http://w3fools.com) :) Aside from the official W3C documentation, which can be hard to read, the official Mozilla Developer Network [**MDN - JavaScript Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). Also read the docs matching your code [**document.querySelector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **Variable 2** example you don't use `eval(example.value)` because it's a String. You would just use `eval(example)`. In your **Variable 1** example you need `example.value` because it would be a DOM Element otherwise. In your **Variable 1** example `example.id` would be the String `code`, where `example.value` is the `value` attrubute, which in the case of `<textarea>`, really looks like `innerHTML`, but since its a form input you use `.value`.

Answer (score 1):

In variable 1 example is an object, an HTML element.

In variable 2 example is a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var example = document.querySelector('#code').value;
```

document.querySelector('#code') returns a DOMElement. You just need to assign the value property of that element to your variable instead of the whole element.